# Printing address of struct members in flexible member array of structs

Tags: c, memory, flexible-array-member

I have a struct which contains a flexible member array:

```
typedef struct bar {
  uint8_t  bar_a;
  uint16_t bar_b;
} bar_t;

typedef struct foo {
  uint16_t foo_a;
  uint_8_t n_bars;
  bar_t    *bars[];
} foo_t;
```

I'm trying to use `foo` and `bar` as data structures to copy data over to `uint8_t buffer[50]`.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_BARS 1;
static uint8_t buffer[50];

static foo_t *
copy_to_buf(void *buf)
{
  int i;
  foo_t *foo = (foo_t *)buf;
  bar_t bar;

  /* Set foo_a */
  foo->foo_a = 1;
  foo->n_bars = NUMBER_OF_BARS;
  /* Set bars */
  for(i=0; i < foo->n_bars; i++) {
    bar.bar_a = 0xFF;
    bar.bar_b = 1234;
    memcpy(&foo->bars[i], &bar, sizeof(bar_t));
  }
  return foo;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  foo_t *foo = copy_to_buf(&buffer);
  printf("foo ... [%p %p %p %p]\n", 
         &foo, &foo->foo_a, &foo->n_bars &foo->bars);
  for(i=0; i < foo->n_bars; i++) {
    printf("bar ... [%p %p %p]\n", 
           &foo->bars[i], &foo->bars[i]->bar_a, &foo->bars[i]->bar_b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now I would have expected this to print the following (i.e. a contiguous block of memory):

```
foo ... [0x1f92 0x1f92 0x1f94 0x1f95]
bar ... [0x1f95 0x1f95 0x1f96]
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
foo ... [0x1f92 0x1f92 0x1f94 0x1f95]
bar ... [0x1f95 0x0 0x1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `copy_to_buf()` does not return a value. No compiler warning?

Comment: How are you getting 4 values printed after `foo...` when the `printf()` only has 3 `%p`?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, not something that resembles your code.

Comment: The `memcpy` makes no sense. You're copying the contents of a structure into a pointer.

Comment: That could be it.

Comment: `bars` probably should be an array of structures, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Either that, or you need to allocate memory for each element with `malloc()`, and copy into that.

Comment: It was the pointers - you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `foo.bars` is an array of pointers, you need to allocate memory for the objects they point to, and then copy to that memory.

```
static foo_t *
copy_to_buf(void *buf)
{
  int i;
  foo_t *foo = (foo_t *)buf;
  bar_t bar;

  /* Set foo_a */
  foo->foo_a = 1;
  foo->n_bars = NUMBER_OF_BARS;
  /* Set bars */
  for(i=0; i < foo->n_bars; i++) {
    bar.bar_a = 0xFF;
    bar.bar_b = 1234;
    foo->bars[i] = malloc(sizeof(bar_t));
    memcpy(foo->bars[i], &bar, sizeof(bar_t));
  }
  return foo;
}
```

Or you could declare it as an array of structures instead of pointers.

```
typedef struct foo {
  uint16_t foo_a;
  uint_8_t n_bars;
  bar_t    bars[];
} foo_t;
```

and change how you access them in `main()`

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  foo_t *foo = copy_to_buf(&buffer);
  printf("foo ... [%p %p %p %p]\n", 
         &foo, &foo->foo_a, &foo->n_bars &foo->bars);
  for(i=0; i < foo->n_bars; i++) {
    printf("bar ... [%p %p %p]\n", 
           &foo->bars[i], &foo->bars[i].bar_a, &foo->bars[i].bar_b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically this, yes. However I changed `bar_t    *bars[];` to `bar_t    bars[];` I hadn't noticed the pointer.